# Transform integral with complex bounds

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, integral-transforms

### Question

I have a line integral given by

$$
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{z_0=a+ib}^{z_1=c+id}dz~ z \\
\\
&= -\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{b^2}{2}-\frac{d^2}{2}+\frac{c^2}{2}+i(-ab+cd)
\end{align}
$$

**For this question I made the integrand $f(z)=z$ for easy math, but in practice it will be non-analytic**. I intend on solving this integral in Python with `scipy`, but in order to do that, I need to be able to represent everything in terms of real values (e.g. $z\equiv\text{Re}(z)+i\text{Im}(z)$).

Normally this would be easy, as I could just break the integrand into real and imaginary parts before distributing the integral (e.g. $\int dz~\text{Re}(z)+i\int dz~\text{Im}(z)$), however the bounds are complex, and I'm not confident of a way to either transform or represent them in terms of real values.

How do I put this into a form where the bounds are no longer complex?

### Set-up

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569378/improper-definite-integration-with-complex-bounds) has been helpful in breaking the integral up into three separate parts, so that I get
$$
I = \underbrace{\int_{z_0}^{a}dz~f(z)}_{I_1}+\underbrace{\int_{a}^{c}dz~f(z)}_{I_2}+\underbrace{\int_{c}^{z_1}dz~f(z)}_{I_3},
$$
such that it gives the same result as the normal way of evaluating $f(z)$. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746726/pythons-scipy-integrate-quad-with-complex-integration-bounds) from Stack Overflow seems to solve the second part of my question, which handles the bounds by further breaking the first and last integrals into two more parts each so that I get
$$
I = \overbrace{\int_{0}^{a}dz~\text{Re}\{f(z+z_0)\}+\int_{0}^{a}dz~\text{Im}\{f(z+z_0)\}}^{I_1}+\overbrace{\int_{a}^{c}dz~f(z)}^{I_2}+\overbrace{\int_{c}^{0}dz~\text{Re}\{f(z+z_1)\}+\int_{c}^{0}dz~\text{Im}\{f(z+z_1)\}}^{I_3}.
$$

Here, everything is in terms of values I can easily plug into `scipy`- but when I evaluate this, it gives me the incorrect result: $I = a^2-c^2+i(ab-cd)$. As a sanity check I put it into `sympy` and came to the same conclusion

```
from sympy import *
a, b, c, d = symbols('a b c d', real=True)
t = Symbol('t', real = True)
f = t

z0 = a+I*b
z1 = c+I*d

I0 = integrate(f, (t, z0, z1)).doit()
actual = re(I0)+I*im(I0)

I1 = integrate(f, (t, z0, a))
I2= integrate(f, (t, a, c))
I3 = integrate(f, (t, c, z1))
cauchy = re(I1+I2+I3)+I*im(I1+I2+I3)

print(actual==cauchy) # prints true

Ia = integrate(re(f.subs({t:t+z0})), (t, 0, a))
Ib = integrate(im(f.subs({t:t+z0})), (t, 0, a))
Ic = integrate(f, (t, a, c))
Id = integrate(re(f.subs({t:t+z1})), (t, c, 0))
Ie = integrate(im(f.subs({t:t+z1})), (t, c, 0))
test = re(Ia+I*Ib+Ic+Id+I*Ie)+I*im(Ia+I*Ib+Ic+Id+I*Ie)

print(actual==test) # prints false
```

My math after the first expansion is definitely wrong, but the issue is that I don't know how to correct it. Could someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: "it will be non-analytic" - then $\int_{z_0}^{z_1}$ is meaningless. You can't integrate a complex function from point to point unless the function is analytic. For general functions only a line integral makes sense, which means specifying the path to use.

Comment: In your case it would be easier to use an antiderivative of $z$, so  $\int_{z_1}^{z_2} z d z = \frac{z^2}{2}\mid_{z_1}^{z_2} = \ldots$.

Comment: @aschelper could you elaborate? Non-analytic integrals can be numerically evaluated. This is the point of my question and why I am using `scipy`- to figure out the correct representation of the entire integral **before** evaluation. Maybe I'm mistaken, and there is a theorem that states non-analytic integrals also cannot have a numeric representation, but I haven't seen it

Comment: @orangeskid Thanks for the comment, but it isn't clear what you are trying to convey (to me). In the problem I outline, $f(z)=z$ is just a test case that is easy to find, but I want to generalize it.

Comment: He's saying that if the integrand isn't analytic, the integral doesn't just depend on the limits of integration ($z_0$ and $z_1$) but on the actual path between them (a line integral is over a path between two points and can't be specified by just saying what the two points are).

Comment: @MPW I see, so it is important to know the nature of the function if you intend on integrating it in the complex plane? I guess what would answer my question is how I choose a path to implement it- like if I knew it had no poles for example

Comment: I see the issue thanks to the commenters. Essentially this is a case of "read the book" where I misunderstood a fundamental principle of complex integration. When I read-up a little more I'll come back to answer this question.

Comment: In general the integral of a $1$ form $\omega$ along a path does not change if : we deform the path, keeping its ends fixed ( homotopy), provided that $d \omega = 0$.  Now for $\omega = f(z) d z$, we have $d \omega = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} d \bar z d z$, and for this to be zero, need $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} =0$, that is $f$ is analytic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aschelper, @orangeskid, and @MPW pointed me in the right direction by explaining that the question I was trying to generalize, "How do I integrate a non-analytic function between two points?" is fundamentally non-trivial. This is standard knowledge in complex analysis that I missed when looking into this class of problem. The path becomes critical to obtaining a good solution, and knowledge of the nature of the integrand in the complex plane is very important to choosing a valid path.

I still want to provide an answer, as the second part of my question, "How do I change the bounds to be real-valued" was never addressed, and I feel as though someone encountering this issue in the future could benefit from it.

A complex line integral along some path parameterized by $\gamma(t)$ is defined by
$$
\int_{\gamma}dz~f(z):=\int_{a}^{b}dt~f(\gamma(t))\gamma^{\prime}(t),
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are end-points of the parameterization.

For my test-case, I choose a linear path from $z_0$ to $z_1$ such that $\gamma(t)=(1-t)z_0+t z_1$ on the interval $0<t<1$, where $\gamma(0)=z_0$ and $\gamma(1)=z_1$. My integral is now

$$
I = \int_{0}^{1}dt~\left[(1-t)z_0+t z_1\right]\left[z_1-z_0\right].
$$

This makes my bounds real-valued, and I can break the integral into real and imaginary parts as stated in my problem. In `sympy`, I confirm the result (using my code from the question)

```
f_of_gamma = (1-t)*z0+t*z1
gamma_prime = z1-z0
integrand = f_of_gamma*gamma_prime

path_int = integrate(integrand, (t, 0, 1))
test = re(path_int)+I*im(path_int)
print(test==actual) # true
```

Putting this into a numerical solver gives the same result as the analytic answer

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from numpy import real, imag

def integrand(t, za, zb):
    def f_of_gamma(t):
        return (1-t)*za+t*zb
    def gamma_prime(t):
        return zb-za
    return f_of_gamma(t)*gamma_prime(t)

def integral(start, stop):
    def real_integrand(t, *args):
        return real(integrand(t, *args))
    
    def imag_integrand(t, *args):
        return imag(integrand(t, *args))
    
    real_result = quad(real_integrand, 0, 1, args=(start, stop))[0]
    imag_result = quad(imag_integrand, 0, 1, args=(start, stop))[0]
    return real_result+1j*imag_result

za, zb = 1+1j*3, 3-1j*5
numerical = integral(za, zb)
print(f"Scipy found: {numerical}, \
        Sympy found: ({actual.subs({a:za.real, b:za.imag, c:zb.real, d:zb.imag})})")
```

Answer = `(-4-8i)`.

In summary, nothing revolutionary was discovered here, but I did figure out the question of "how do I transform the bounds". It turns out that there is a well-established definition for the complex path integral that uses parameterization to handle it. For my first question, I'll need to think deeply about the way I can choose a path for a non-analytic function before tackling the problem- something that won't be accomplished on this forum.

Thanks all for the help.